# Getting constants and subclasses

Tags: ruby, class, module, ruby-1.9

1. What is the shortest way to get the constants belonging to a module `A`? If I do `A.constants`, it gives an array of the symbolized name of the constants of `A`, not the array of `A`'s constants. I am particularly asking this because with `ancestors`, it is more straightforward: `A.ancestors` gives back the array of its ancestors, not the array of the symbolized name of the ancestors.
2. What is the shortest way to get an array of immediate subclasses of class `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
class A;        end
class A::B < A; end
```

1. Use `const_get` to access constants of modules by symbol:

   ```
   A.constants.map { |constant| A.const_get constant }
   # => [A::B]
   ```
2. You could search for subclasses among all existing classes:

   ```
   ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |klass| klass.superclass == A }
   # => [A::B]
   ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |klass| klass.superclass == A::B }
   # => []
   ```